# Hybris - Adding Service product to main product

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I would like to know what is the best approach to add service products to a main product.

Say for example, in Autocare we have Standard Oil Change (Main Product) and Synthetic Oil change (Main Product) and there are services products tied to it like tire pressure check, wheel balance, Air filter inspect, etc. Say Standard Oil change will have 6 services tied to it and Synthetic Oil Change will have  12 services to it.

When the user adds Standard Oil change to the cart, it should show all the services relates this this product in the cart.

So i will adding 12 Service Product to Hybris DB altogether and i can add these service products to any Main Products. Could anyone let me know what is the best approach and how we can make realtionship between Main Product and Service products. Another thing is the Service product will not be visible when the user searches for product, but it will be visible in the PDP once he selects that product.

Appreciate your help on this. Advance Thanks!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link products with each other, based on a type of relationship, you should make use of the [ProductReference](https://help.sap.com/doc/c14b940047cf4dfeb4332e93d8afad8f/2005/en-US/de/hybris/platform/catalog/model/ProductReferenceModel.html) datamodel. This allows you to link 2 products and specifying what their relationship is with the [ProductReferenceType](https://help.sap.com/doc/c14b940047cf4dfeb4332e93d8afad8f/2005/en-US/de/hybris/platform/catalog/enums/ProductReferenceTypeEnum.html) property.

By default, it's used a lot for cross selling, upselling, accessories,... It also has a default type available called `CONSISTS_OF`. This one fits your requirements perfectly.

For your example:
You would have your product `Standard Oil Change`, that will have 6 product references. One for each service. The type of this reference should be `CONSISTS_OF`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. This really helps a lot and straightforward and clean approach. Just checking if you have any other thoughts to design this.

- Thanks

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you will need to create something custom if you want to visualize this in the cart. There is a cartSuggestionComponent, but that is not for a specific product. There is also the productReferencesComponent for product detail page. You could look there and base your implementation on this

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable and quick responses